# Pandas idiomatic way to custom fillna

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series data in the following format, where a value indicates an accumulated amount since the past recording. What I want to do is "spread" that accumulated amount over the past periods containing NaN so that this input:

```
s = pd.Series([0, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 75, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 50],
              pd.date_range(start="Jan 1 2016", end="Jan 10 2016", freq='D'))

2016-01-01      0.0
2016-01-02      0.0
2016-01-03      NaN
2016-01-04      NaN
2016-01-05     75.0
2016-01-06      NaN
2016-01-07      NaN
2016-01-08      NaN
2016-01-09      NaN
2016-01-10     50.0
```

Becomes this output:

```
2016-01-01     0.0
2016-01-02     0.0
2016-01-03    25.0
2016-01-04    25.0
2016-01-05    25.0
2016-01-06    10.0
2016-01-07    10.0
2016-01-08    10.0
2016-01-09    10.0
2016-01-10    10.0
```

Is there an idiomatic Pandas way to do this rather than just do a for loop over the data? I've tried a variety of things involving `fillna`, `dropna`, `isnull`, doing `shift` to check the next value, etc but I can't see how to put the pieces together.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think there is a built-in way, and, unfortunately, you may have to end up looping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work, for each chunk of missing values, create a group variable with `cumsum`(from the end of the series) and then perform a grouped average operation on each chunk:

```
s.groupby(s.notnull()[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]).transform(lambda g: g[-1]/g.size)

#2016-01-01     0.0
#2016-01-02     0.0
#2016-01-03    25.0
#2016-01-04    25.0
#2016-01-05    25.0
#2016-01-06    10.0
#2016-01-07    10.0
#2016-01-08    10.0
#2016-01-09    10.0
#2016-01-10    10.0
#Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

---

Or another option:

```
s.groupby(s.shift().notnull().cumsum()).transform(lambda g: g[-1]/g.size)

#2016-01-01     0.0
#2016-01-02     0.0
#2016-01-03    25.0
#2016-01-04    25.0
#2016-01-05    25.0
#2016-01-06    10.0
#2016-01-07    10.0
#2016-01-08    10.0
#2016-01-09    10.0
#2016-01-10    10.0
#Freq: D, dtype: float64
```